# Taking single value from a cell with multiple inserted values multiplied by single value from another cell with multiple inserted values

Tags: sqlite

I am currently working on a database trying to learn different techniques and was wondering if there is a way to take a single value from a cell that has a variable amount of inserted data and multiply that specific value by a single value from another cell that has the same amount of data inserted.

```
Customer_Number | Book_ID | Quantity | Price                | Total                  
data            | values  | 2, 3, 5  | 109.20, 72.80, 59.15 | 732.55
```

The total should be 732.55 if done correctly but currently the generated constraint Quantity * Price will only take the first values in each cell and calculate the total. I want to be able to take 1st value * 1st value, 2nd value * 2nd value, 3rd value * 3rd value and have them in the Total cell after. The amount of inserted quantities is a variable but will always be the same as the amount of inserted prices.

(I know about normalization, I just want to see if you can select a single value from multiple inserted into a cell)

Comment: In relational data bases you usually aim to put those individual pairs into separate rows in a  table,  then they are much easier to work with.   This is called normalizing a database.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: the first technique to learn is how to structure that data.  do not put them in comma delimited lists inside a cell. put each value in its own column - normalize.